# Issue with scope of a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a directive like,

```
mainApp.directive('myMenu',function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope :{menuItems : "=menuItems"},
            compile: function(element, attributes) {
                var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes){
                    for (i = 0;i<$scope.menuItems.length;i++){
                         element.append('<li><a href="#home">'+$scope.menuItems[i].name+'</a></li>');
                    }
                }
                return linkFunction;
            }

        }
    });
```

I am using it like below in my HTML

```
   <my-menu menuItems="menuItems"></my-menu>
```

But in the console I am getting an error like 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Comment: why don't you check for `undefined` before looping `if($scope.menuItems)`

Comment: see if it works using menuItems.length instead of $scope.menuItems.length

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that, then the linking phase is executed the menuitems may not be loaded so `$scope.menuItems` may be undefined.

A better solution could be

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

mainApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.menuItems = [{
    name: 'one'
  }, {
    name: 'two'
  }, {
    name: 'three'
  }, {
    name: 'four'
  }];
})

mainApp.directive('myMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      menuItems: "="
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">{{item.name}}<a href="#home"></a></li></ul>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <my-menu menu-items="menuItems"></my-menu>
</div>
```

---

If you can't use template then

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

mainApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.menuItems = [{
    name: 'one'
  }, {
    name: 'two'
  }, {
    name: 'three'
  }, {
    name: 'four'
  }];
})

mainApp.directive('myMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      menuItems: "=menuItems"
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
      $scope.$watch('menuItems', function(value) {
        element.empty();
        angular.forEach(value, function(item) {
          element.append('<li><a href="#home">' + item.name + '</a></li>');
        });
      });
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <my-menu menu-items="menuItems"></my-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use it inside the template, as i need a different behavior based on the data coming.

Comment: I know this will work, but in my case iI need it insde a function

Comment: its caused by the naming, posted the answer

Comment: @robin yes.... I had already changed... but forgot to mention it... but without a watch any changes on the array will not get reflected

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.$eval(attributes.menuItems)` inside compile function to get menuItems

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was with the name I used, like menuItems in directive should be equal to menu-items, solved the issue by repalcing the menuItems to menu.